# What is the fastest way to extract 1 file from a zip file which contain a lot of file?

Tags: java, unzip, compression

I tried the [java.util.zip](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html&ei=-u-STYe3A4O3cIP9sYkH&usg=AFQjCNFJyvU5FyaBROuxABMAAmZBZ197HQ) package, it is too slow.

Then I found [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) and [7z jbinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/index.html) but they are also lacking something.
The LZMA SDK does not provide a kind of documentation/tutorial of how-to-use, it is very frustrating. No javadoc.

While the 7z jbinding does not provide a simple way to extract only 1 file, however, it only provide way to extract all the content of the zip file. Moreover, it does not provide a way to specify a location to place the unzipped file.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 16):

What does your code with `java.util.zip` look like and how big of a zip file are you dealing with?

I'm able to extract a 4MB entry out of a 200MB zip file with 1,800 entries in roughly a second with this:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("your.file");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("your.zip");
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(bin);
ZipEntry ze = null;
while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (ze.getName().equals("your.file")) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        out.close();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: We are doing a web app for outsider usage.....we are talking about 20 request per second. We've examine that the speed of unzipping a file using java.util.zip would be between 0.5s to 2s. That's slow.

Comment: I assume you're talking about 20 requests per second that need a single file out of a zip. Why not just completely unzip those ahead of time and serve them directly from the file system?

Comment: your code would be even faster if you had a BufferedInputStream between the FileInputStream and the ZipInputStream.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you do a zin.close() at the end?

Comment: whether zin.closeEntry() is not required ?

Comment: Reading the whole ZIP file to extract only one entry is not a good way. Using getEntry() method of ZipFile or using FileSystem is much better.

Answer (score 13):

I have not benchmarked the speed but with java 7 or greater, I extract a file as follows.
I would imagine that it's faster than the [ZipFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) API:

A short example extracting `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` from a zip file `test.zip`:

```
// file to extract from zip file
String file = "MANIFEST.MF";
// location to extract the file to
File outputLocation = new File("D:/temp/", file);
// path to the zip file
Path zipFile = Paths.get("D:/temp/test.zip");

// load zip file as filesystem
try (FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFile)) {
    // copy file from zip file to output location
    Path source = fileSystem.getPath("META-INF/" + file);
    Files.copy(source, outputLocation.toPath());
}
```

Comment: Works, and lightning fast ... this should be the accepted answer (assuming Java 7 or higher).

Answer (score 5):

Use a [ZipFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) rather than a [ZipInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

Although the documentation does not indicate this (it's in the docs for `JarFile`), it should use random-access file operations to read the file. Since a ZIPfile contains a directory at a known location, this means a LOT less IO has to happen to find a particular file.

Some caveats: to the best of my knowledge, the Sun implementation uses a memory-mapped file. This means that your virtual address space has to be large enough to hold the file as well as everything else in your JVM. Which may be a problem for a 32-bit server. On the other hand, it may be smart enough to avoid memory-mapping on 32-bit, or memory-map just the directory; I haven't tried.

Also, if you're using multiple files, be sure to use a `try`/`finally` to ensure that the file is closed after use.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below assumes you know both the target zip filepath and the target entry filepath inside it.

No need to iterate through the files as `ZipFile` provides a method `getEntry` to retrieve an entry directly as well as methods to get a `byte[]` or a `FileInputStream` with its contents.

In this example it reads a protobuf binary file with about 340KB from a zip file in ~11ms. One may use a similar approach to read any other file type.

```java
    /* Relevant imports */
    import com.google.protobuf.Message;
    import com.google.protobuf.Parser;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
    import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
    
    public final class ZipFileUtils {

        ...

        public static <T extends Message> Message readMessageFromZip(
                                                final Path zipPath, 
                                                final Path entryPath, 
                                                final Parser<T> messageParser        
                                             ) throws IOException {
            try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath.toFile())) {
                ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry(entryPath.toString());
                return messageParser.parseFrom(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry));
            }
        }
    }
```